# Error "The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'." flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to fetch users'Users data from Firebase Firestore. For that I created a model class.And also in those data has a birthday parameter I tried to define that in model but show this error "The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'"

[image]

My code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Users UsersFromJson(String str) => Users.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String UsersToJson(Users data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Users {
  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.url,
    required this.name,
    required this.birthday,
  });
  String id;
  String name;
  String url;
  DateTime birthday;

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Users(
    id: json["id"] ?? "",
    name: json["name"] ?? "",
    url: json["url"] ?? "",
    birthday: json["birthday"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]) : null,
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "url": url,
    "birthday": birthday?.toString(),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of two codes:

```dart
class Users {
  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.url,
    required this.name,
    required this.birthday,
  });
  String id;
  String name;
  String url;
  DateTime? birthday;

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Users(
    id: json["id"] ?? "",
    name: json["name"] ?? "",
    url: json["url"] ?? "",
    birthday: json["birthday"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]) : null,
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "url": url,
    "birthday": birthday?.toString(),
  };
}
```

---

```dart
class Users {
  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.url,
    required this.name,
    required this.birthday,
  });
  String id;
  String name;
  String url;
  DateTime birthday;

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Users(
    id: json["id"] ?? "",
    name: json["name"] ?? "",
    url: json["url"] ?? "",
    birthday: json["birthday"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]) : DateTime.now(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "url": url,
    "birthday": birthday?.toString(),
  };
}
```

However, I recommend that you use the first code more, because if the `birthday` field is null, you can show the user that there is no data.

If you use the second code, I don't think there is any way to check if the `birthday` field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `birthday` nullable. So replace

```
DateTime birthday;
```

with

```
DateTime? birthday;
```

If you don't want it to be nullable you could instead put a non-null fallback like `DateTime.now()` for example like

```
    birthday:
        json["birthday"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]) : DateTime.now(),
```

Answer (score 1):

2 work arounds

1. pass `non nullable` value to `birthday`:

   ```
   birthday: DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]) ?? DateTime.now(),
   ```
2. make `birthday nullable`

   ```
   DateTime? birthday
   ```

   with this method you can keep the existing line of the code. Your error will no longer display.